# Symbol generated for local static const variable?

Tags: c++, linker

I'm using a rapidjson in a shared library, which at some point starts defining a method like this:

```
    template<unsigned parseFlags, typename SEncoding, typename TEncoding, typename InputStream, typename OutputStream>
    RAPIDJSON_FORCEINLINE void ParseStringToStream(InputStream& is, OutputStream& os) {
//!@cond RAPIDJSON_HIDDEN_FROM_DOXYGEN
#define Z16 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        static const char escape[256] = {
            Z16, Z16, 0, 0,'\"', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,'/',
            Z16, Z16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,'\\', 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0,'\b', 0, 0, 0,'\f', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,'\n', 0,
            0, 0,'\r', 0,'\t', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            Z16, Z16, Z16, Z16, Z16, Z16, Z16, Z16
        };
#undef Z16
//!@endcond
```

What I don't understand is why this generates a relocation:

Output of readelf:

```
823: 0000000000051b00   256 OBJECT  UNIQUE DEFAULT   14 _ZZN9rapidjson13GenericReaderINS_4UTF8IcEES2_NS_12CrtAllocatorEE19ParseStringToStreamILj0ES2_S2_9PhpStreamNS4_11StackStreamIcEEEEvRT2_RT3_E6escape
```

If the variable is not extern, why the symbol with STB_GNU_UNIQUE binding? Wouldn't just a static offset from the instruction pointer suffice to get to this data?

Comment: Are you building with optimizations enabled?

Comment: @JesperJuhl yes, but it happens on debug builds as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the function is being inlined because inlining has been explicitly requested, but while the compiler is inlining the instructions, it has decided to only emit one copy of the `escape` array, which the linker will merge across translation units, so there will be only one copy in the entire program, so the compiler needs to emit a symbol so that `escape` can be found by each inlined copy of the function.

(Note: Technically, the standard mandates that a `static` local variable declared in the body of an inline function with external linkage has a unique address. However, I looked at the source, and it appears that `escape` is not odr-used, so this unique address is not observable; the compiler could have chosen to inline the content of this array into each translation unit. However, this wastes an additional 256 bytes per translation unit.)

Comment: Thanks, it sort of makes sense, but I still don't understand why the R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT relocation, why this symbol needs to be resolved at runtime and not at link time when the several compilation units using this method are linked together.

Comment: @Artefacto isn't that because it's in a shared library?

Comment: Why does it matter? Couldn't the data be put at (different) constant offsets from the instructions that access it, even if these instructions are loaded at different addresses as the library is loaded is itself loaded at different addresses?

Comment: @Artefacto Both the shared library and the main program (and possibly other shared libraries loaded by the program) can contain their own copy of rapidjson, so I think what I said above applies.